# htaccess - removing preceding index.php but retain some parameters

Tags: .htaccess

For example I have this URL: `http://www.domain.com/index.php?mod=category&continent=Asia`
I wanted to truncate the URL by removing the index.php, so the output URL would be: `http://www.domain.com/?mod=category&continent=Asia`

Is there any alternative(preferably shorter) code than this one:

```
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-f
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-d
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !(index.php)    [NC]
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ blah-blah-blah   [L]
```

Comment: RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]    Will this code do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are saying is that you want your external URIs of the form

```
http://www.domain.com/?mod=category&continent=Asia
```

to be processed by `DOCROOT/index.php`

Specifying a DirectoryIndex of index.php will achieve this as will

```
RewriteRule ^$   index.php
```

The rewrite engine will automatically append the query string.

To truncate the site URIs in your web pages, you need to change the HTML.